# What is/how do I get the Device Tree Compiler?

Tags: zynq

I am trying to program a Xilinx zc706 board, which involves building a Linux kernel and setting up the bootloader. I am following the workflow given [here](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Getting+Started).

The first step after downloading stuff involves making the device tree compiler, which I need to get UBoot, which I need to start up linux. I obtained the source for DTC off github, but when I went into the SDK shell, moved to the directory, and entered "MAKE", I got an error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
>
> -x was unexpected at this time.
>
> "       " LEX convert-dtsv0-lexer.lex.c
>
> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL,flex -oconvert-dtsv0-lexer.lex.c convert-dtsv0-lexer.1, ...) failed.

and then followed with some other stuff saying files could not be found, presumably because this first thing failed.

I have no idea how to read this error, it's gibberish to me. Can someone explain either what's wrong with this build, or how I can get either the DTC or UBoot I would need to run a Zynq chip?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making things much harder on yourself by doing manually what PetaLinux will do automatically for you.  Unless you're a die-hard Linux purist and want to build your embedded Linux system from scratch, you should stop reading after the first paragraph of the link you posted and head to the [PetaLinux wiki page](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/PetaLinux).

Follow the steps in the PetaLinux Tools Reference Guide to get your project up and running.  It will handle building u-boot, rootfs, linux kernel, and device tree compiler for you (petalinux-* commands) and you can focus on developing your application.